# Apache Authentication with ManifoldCF

Tags: apache, authentication

I'm trying to connect ManifoldCF to an internal wiki at my company. The ManifoldCF wiki connector supplies a username and password field for the wiki api, however, at my company, a username and password is required to connect to the apache server running the wiki site, and after that authentication takes place, those credentials are passed on to the wiki api.

So, essentially, I need a way to have ManifoldCF pass my windows credentials on when trying to make its connection. Using the api login fields does not work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to create an Authority Connection of type "Active Directory".  Then, attach it to the wiki crawl Job.  When you create the Authority Connection with your windows credentials ManifoldCF will attempt to establish a connection to the authorization server, and show the connection status.  If the status is "connected" then you should be good to go.
I hope this helps.  Jim